# In Mathematica, how do I compile the function Outer[] for an arbitrary number of arguments?

Tags: compilation, wolfram-mathematica

If I want to find all possible sums from two lists `list1` and `list2`, I use the `Outer[]` function with the specification of `Plus` as the combining operator:

`In[1]= list1 = {a, b}; list2 = {c, d}; Outer[Plus, list1, list2]`

`Out[1]= {{a + c, a + d}, {b + c, b + d}}`

If I want to be able to handle an arbitrary number of lists, say a list of lists,

`In[2]= listOfLists={list1, list2};`

then the only way I know how to find all possible sums is to use the `Apply[]` function (which has the short hand `@@`) along with `Join`:

`In[3]= argumentsToPass=Join[{Plus},listOfLists]`

`Out[3]= {Plus, {a, b}, {c, d}}`

`In[4]= Outer @@ argumentsToPass`

`Out[4]=  {{a + c, a + d}, {b + c, b + d}}`

or simply

`In[5]= Outer @@ Join[{Plus},listOfLists]`

`Out[5]=  {{a + c, a + d}, {b + c, b + d}}`

The problem comes when I try to compile:

`In[6]= Compile[ .....  Outer @@ Join[{Plus},listOfLists] .... ]`

`Compile::cpapot: "Compilation of Outer@@Join[{Plus},listOfLists]] is not supported for the function argument Outer. The only function arguments supported are Times, Plus, or List. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. "`

The thing is, I *am* using a supported function, namely `Plus`.  The problem seems to be solely with the `Apply[]` function.  Because if I give it a fixed number of lists to outer-plus together, it works fine

`In[7]= Compile[{{bob, _Integer, 1}, {joe, _Integer, 1}}, Outer[Plus, bob, joe]]`

`Out[7]= CompiledFunction[{bob, joe}, Outer[Plus, bob, joe],-CompiledCode-]`

but as soon as I use `Apply`, it breaks

`In[8]= Compile[{{bob, _Integer, 1}, {joe, _Integer, 1}},  Outer @@ Join[{Plus}, {bob, joe}]]`

`Out[8]= Compile::cpapot: "Compilation of Outer@@Join[{Plus},{bob,joe}] is not supported for the function argument Outer. The only function arguments supported are Times, Plus, or List. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function."`

**So my questions is**: Is there a way to circumvent this error or, alternatively, a way to compute all possible sums of elements pulled from an arbitrary number of lists in a compiled function?

(Also, I'm not sure if "compilation" is an appropriate tag.  Please advise.)

Thanks so much.

Comment: About how many lists are you expecting, and how long are the lists?  Depending on the answer, Compile may not be the fastest way to perform this operation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way it to use `With`, to create a compiled function programmatically:

```
Clear[makeCompiled];
makeCompiled[lnum_Integer] :=
 With[{listNames = Table[Unique["list"], {lnum}]},
   With[{compileArgs = {#, _Integer, 1} & /@ listNames},
      Compile @@ Join[Hold[compileArgs],
        Replace[Hold[Outer[Plus, listNames]], 
          Hold[Outer[Plus, {x__}]] :> Hold[Outer[Plus, x]], {0}]]]];
```

It can probably be done prettier, but it works. For example:

```
In[22]:= p2 = makeCompiled[2]
Out[22]= CompiledFunction[{list13,list14},Outer[Plus,list13,list14],-CompiledCode-]

In[23]:= p2[{1,2,3},{4,5}]
Out[23]= {{5,6},{6,7},{7,8}}

In[24]:= p3 = makeCompiled[3]
Out[24]= CompiledFunction[{list15,list16,list17},Outer[Plus,list15,list16,list17],-CompiledCode-]

In[25]:= p3[{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}]
Out[25]= {{{9,10},{10,11}},{{10,11},{11,12}}}
```

HTH

Edit:

You can hide the compiled function behind another one, so that it is created at run-time and you don't actually see it:

```
In[33]:= 
Clear[computeSums]
computeSums[lists : {__?NumberQ} ..] := makeCompiled[Length[{lists}]][lists];

In[35]:= computeSums[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}]

Out[35]= {{5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}}
```

You face an overhead of compiling in this case, since you create then a compiled function afresh every time. You can fight this overhead rather elegantly with memoization, using `Module` variables for persistence, to localize your memoized definitions:

```
In[44]:= 
Clear[computeSumsMemoized];
Module[{compiled},
  compiled[n_] := compiled[n] = makeCompiled[n];
  computeSumsMemoized[lists : {__?NumberQ} ..] := compiled[Length[{lists}]][lists]];

In[46]:= computeSumsMemoized[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}]

Out[46]= {{5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}}
```

Comment: But wouldn't I have to recompile for all possible number of lists?  I want a single compiled function which, depending on inputs, can handle different numbers of lists.

Comment: The latter function (computeSumsMemoized) does exactly that. When it first time sees a number of lists (say,3), that it did not see before, it does compile. But all other times that you supply 3 lists, it will not recompile - it will use the memoized definition (already compiled function). But note that for Outer, while you can get some speed-up from compilation (especially if you compile to C), it won't probably be dramatic.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I missed the point a bit. This is not a single compiled function that handles any combination of lists, indeed. Rather, this is a collection (hash-table) of compiled functions, automatically created on demand. For a single compiled function, you indeed have a problem with `Apply` and `Outer`, and I don't know off the top of my head how to solve that. But, in practice, does it make that much of a  difference? You will face small performance hits due to compilation every time that you supply a new number of lists, but this will only happen once for a given number of lists.

Comment: Gotcha.  Boy, this seems like a complicated solution to a simple problem, but it may well be that Mathematica simply offers no better way.  Thanks so much for the extensive help!

Comment: The problem is actually not so simple. In a procedural language, it would require nested loops with a number of loops depending on a number of input arguments - and I wouldn't know off-hand how to do this say in C or Java, given exactly this formulation (no recursion or other tricks allowed).

Answer (score 4):

This is my first post.  I hope I get this right.

If your inputs are lists of integers, I am skeptical of the value of compiling this function, at least in Mathematica 7.

For example:

```
f = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {b, _Integer, 1}, {c, _Integer, 1}, {d, _Integer, 1}, {e, _Integer, 1}}, 
        Outer[Plus, a, b, c, d, e]
    ];

a = RandomInteger[{1, 99}, #] & /@ {12, 32, 19, 17, 43};

Do[f @@ a, {50}] // Timing

Do[Outer[Plus, ##] & @@ a, {50}] // Timing
```

The two Timings are not significantly different for me, but of course this is only one sample.  The point is merely that Outer is already fairly fast compared to the compiled version.

If you have reasons other than speed for compilation, you may find some use in Tuples instead of Outer, but you still have the constraint of compiled functions requiring tensor input.

```
f2 = Compile[{{array, _Integer, 2}}, 
      Plus @@@ Tuples@array
    ];

f2[{{1, 3, 7}, {13, 25, 41}}]
```

If your inputs are large, then a different approach may be in order.  Given a list of lists of integers, this function will return the possible sums and the number of ways to get each sum:

```
f3 = CoefficientRules@Product[Sum[x^i, {i, p}], {p, #}] &;

f3[{{1, 3, 7}, {13, 25, 41}}]
```

This should prove to be far more memory efficient in many cases.

```
a2 = RandomInteger[{1, 999}, #] & /@ {50, 74, 55, 55, 90, 57, 47, 79, 87, 36};

f3[a2]; // Timing

MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

This took 3 seconds and minimal memory, but attempting the application of Outer to a2 terminated the kernel with "No more memory available."